# Tikz inline plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

I'm using the Tikz package to create a series of plots directly in my main .tex file. I opted for this method because the labels match perfectly the font and size of my main file even if I scale or not the plot.
Now I encountered a common problem that is the one related to the *TeX capacity exceeded*. The suggestion to overcome this problem seems to be to externalize the plots. About that I have two problems

1. If I create the plot outside my main .tex file, will the font and size of the labels be math with the main .tex file even if I scale the figure?
2. If yes, can someone describe the procedure to follow? I searched on other threads but I didn't fully understand the procedure. To write my .tex files I use TexMaker.

Comment: You should have _very_ big diagram to have a TeX capacity exceeded. The Ti*k*Z manual can be compiled in one go... The more probable problem is a bug somewhere in your diagram. The faster approach is to try to use `tikzexternalize` library, which is automatic (see Ti*k*Z manual around page 666)

Comment: Hello Rmano, thank you for your reply. The problem is that I have many plots (around 16). I could reduce the number of points for each graph but I'm afraid it could lead to lower quality of the plots.

Comment: The other option is using a `standalone` class file manually (this is handy too), be sure to use the same fonts of your main file, and do not scale the generated `.pdf`  when you load it via `\includegraphics`.

Comment: in the `pgfplots` manual there are *hundreds* of plots. Are you sure you are not overdoing with point density? Over a certain number is even bad for the plot: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318524/38080

Comment: Yes, this could be an option, but one of the reasons why I came to use inline tikz is because it's exactly match the font

Comment: Using `tikzexternalize` the font is matched too, and also if you use `standalone` correctly --- the only thing you have to check is that you do not scale anything.

Comment: Probably you are right, one of the plots has 13000 points.

Comment: If printed/viewed 20cm wide, 13000 points mean one point every 15 μm. ;-)

Comment: Are you changing the font size frequently?  In that case externalize is probably the way to go.  (Personally, I have never gotten shell escapes to work.)

Comment: If you want to see how the `external` library can be used, have a look at e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253181/95441 and the duplicate question that it links to.